# jQuery Plugins are not available during ajax complete callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, postmessage

I'm using the jQuery fancybox plugin to display an iframe with contextual information about a record when a user clicks on a link.

The .fancybox() plugin is not found at the time the ajax success callback runs. Similar to the following:

```
$(function() {
    Widgets = {
        show_dialog: function(width, height) {
            $('.fancybox').fancybox({ fancybox settings here});
        }
    }
});
```

I can tell that fancybox is loaded and available when the above Widgets object is defined from checking a breakpoint just after it.  I can also fix the calling of this function by wrapping the show_dialog function in a anonymous function that scopes $ like the following:

```
$(function() {
    Widgets = {
        show_dialog: function($) { return function(width, height) {
            $('.fancybox').fancybox({ fancybox settings here});
        }; }($)
    }
});
```

More background... I'm using postMessage jQuery plugin to send the message from a child frame to the parent frame, if that matters (I don't think it should)

Can anyone explain what's going on? It almost feels like $ is reassigned later in the execution of the page but I'm not loading it anywhere.

**EDIT: Updated scoping of fancybox to $('.fancybox').fancybox(**

Comment: Are both the iframe and the parent pages in the same domain?

Comment: Nope, different domains, thus using http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/ to send the message to the parent frame.  Message gets there fine.

Comment: Little more detal... The parent function that is calling this function has $.fancybox defined. This function is called via window['this_funtion'].apply( e.source, args ).

I tried changing e.source to null with no affect towards the error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you need to attach that call to an object of some kind, ie: `$("a.text").fancybox({opts});`

What's the error you're seeing?  Are you actually executing this code from the framed page or the parent?

Comment: My bad, it is attached to an object, $('.fancybox').fancybox({opts});

The actual error is `$('.fancybox').fancybox is not a function`